# Необходима небольшая правка Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть [готовый Google Script](https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets), который позволяет передавать данные из form на странице в гугл таблицу. Скрипт написан так, что при отправке данных он добавляет timestamp в формате дд.мм.гггг чч:мм:сс в одну ячейку. Как необходимо отредактировать код, чтобы timestamp вставлял дату в одну ячейку, а время в соседнюю, а уже после этого вставлялись остальные данные? Нужна помощь или совет. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо написать функцию, которая будет форматировать дату (класс Date) в формат "дд.мм.гггг", скажем, `formatToDate` и функцию, которая будет форматировать дату в формат чч:мм:сс, скажем, `formatToTime`, изменить

```js
return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
```

на

```js
 return header === 'date' ? formatToDate(new Date()) : (header === 'time' ? formatToTime(new Date()) : e.parameter[header])
```

И, разумеется, в гугл-таблице добавить соответствующие заголовки взамен timestamp